# Group and apply 'LIKE' filters to product collection (x AND y AND ....) OR (z AND a ...)

Tags: magento-1, filter, product-collection

How to filter product collection as follows

```
WHERE (`att1` LIKE '%val1%' AND `att1` LIKE '%val2%') 
OR (`att2` LIKE '%val1%' AND `att2` LIKE '%val2%')
```

the number of 'LIKE' statements inside groups and 'AND' groups is unspecified but always >0

Comment: please check my answer and let me know if it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter as collection like this example:

```
$collection->getSelect()->where(new Zend_Db_Expr("(`att1` LIKE '%val1%' AND `att1` LIKE '%val2%') 
OR (`att2` LIKE '%val1%' AND `att2` LIKE '%val2%')"));
```

Comment: thanks. I have already tried it. Theoretically this could work but it's not an universal solution because attributes can't always be referred to as `att1` or `e`.`att1`. Sometimes they're 'IF' expressions and are not added to a query(via joins) if not passed via, e.g., 'addAttributeToFilter'. Filtering products by name or custom attribute in that way returns an exception.